# How to match a string to regex based on a certain index?

Tags: c++, regex

I am working on a small project of mine, and I need to match a string to a regex value, and the first character of the match needs to start ***exactly*** at a certain index.

I need to do this in C++, but can't find a method or function that seems like it would work on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex).

Eg. if I put in the string `Stack overflow` into the pattern `f.ow`
and an index of 3, it should return `false`. But if I set the index to 10, it should return `true` and allow me to find out what actually matched (`flow`). And if I put in an index of 11, it should also return `false`.

Comment: when you want your regex to work after a certain index, you could just create a new string, beginning from that index. `std::string( s.begin()+3, s.end() );`. Whether this is possible like you want it, idk.

Comment: @Dimfred - you don't need to create a new string, just make the iterator = s.begin()+3; etc.. and use iterators in the search function. But there are problems doing this, like anchors `^` and other things like assertions (behind if supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function, hope this will work for you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
bool exactRegexMatch(string str,int index){
    regex reg("f(.)ow");
    return regex_match(str.substr(index), reg);
}
int main(){
    if(exactRegexMatch("Stack Overflow",10)){
        cout<<"True"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"False"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the new ECMAScript hits C++ there might be a lookbehind in the regex like `(?<=92_)f.ow` which won't match. What do you do then ?

Comment: This looks like it should work.

Comment: @sLn Why would this break if the new ECMAScript hits C++?

Answer (score 1):

> How to match a string to regex based on a certain index?

Pass the substring starting from the index as the string argument, and add `^` to the beginning of the regex so that it only matches when the pattern starts from the beginning of the substring.

Comment: If the new ECMAScript hits C++ there might be a lookbehind in the regex like `(?<=92_)f.ow` which won't match. What do you do then ?

Comment: @sln Then scrap the idea of using a substring, and prepend `^.{i}` to the regex (where `i` is the index).

Answer (score 0):

This uses the whole string by constructing the regex.

```
strRx = `"^[\\S\\s]{" + strOffset + "}(f.ow)";
// make a regex out of strRx
```

or, use ***iterators*** to jump to the location to start matching from

```
bool FindInString( std::string& sOut, std::string& sInSrc, int offset )
{
    static std::regex Rx("(f.ow)");

    sOut = "";
    bool bRet = false;
    std::smatch _M;
    std::string::const_iterator _Mstart = sInSrc.begin() + offset;
    std::string::const_iterator _Mend   = sInSrc.end();

    if ( regex_search( _Mstart, _Mend, _M, Rx ) )
    {
        // Check that it matched at exactly the _Mstart position
        if ( _M[1].first == _Mstart )
        {
            sOut = std::string(_M[1].first, _M[1].second);
            bRet = true;
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}
```